# I opened a channel and sent 1500 msats to my counterparty. Why can I still not receive anything?

Tags: ln-opening-channels, ln-channel-balance-management, lightning-development-kit

I'm aware that when I first open a channel, all of the channel balance is on my side, so I can only send and not receive.

So, I opened a channel and then sent my counterparty 1500 millisatoshis—but I can still only send and not receive. What's going on?

I'm using Lightning Dev Kit (LDK).

Comment: What implementation is at the other end of the channel, also LDK?

Comment: If using `ldk-sample`, can you show the output of `listchannels` commands?

Comment: To be clear, I've asked and answered this question as it's a commonly asked question on the LDK discord

Comment: Does the implementation on the other side matter? I would assume that LDK does not permit capacity to be transferred when the remainder falls below the channel reserve. And since it takes two to tango…

Answer (score 2):

This is an effect of the [channel reserve](https://docs.rs/lightning/latest/lightning/util/config/struct.ChannelHandshakeConfig.html#structfield.their_channel_reserve_proportional_millionths).

The channel reserve is enforced to ensure each counterparty always has something to lose, if they were to try to cheat. By default, the channel reserve is 1% of the channel capacity, and LDK sets a hard minimum of 1000sats.

Therefore, if you were to send enough such that more than `max(1% of channel capacity, 1000sats)` were on your counterparty’s side, your available balance for receive would increase.

Since you only sent 1500msats (1.5sats), the amount is still below the channel reserve for the counterparty and none of their funds can move to you.

Comment: In the concrete case this is not a plausible explanation (with these values), as the 1500 sats sent is more than 1000.

Comment: 1500 *msats, not sats :) Is there some way to clarify?

Comment: I've added another sentence to clarify the two different units in play

Comment: Indeed, I misread it for sats. 1500 msats is way below the 1000 sats minimum capacity.