# Balances do not add up to channel capacity

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon, ln-opening-channels, ln-channel-balance-management

Using `LND`, I opened a channel with `--local_amt=1100000` and `--push_amt=500000`. I would think that would open a channel with a capacity of 1100000, a local balance of 600000 and a remote balance of 500000.

But when I run `listchannels`, it tells me the following:

```
"capacity": "1100000",
"local_balance": "596530",
"remote_balance": "500000",
```

Where did the other 3470 satoshis go?

**EDIT**: There is a separate reserve balance of 10000 satoshis which I can see by running the `walletbalance` command, so it doesn't seem like it is part of that.

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/116743/5406